# Wordpress: url to image contains uploads// - How to change the double slash?

Tags: wordpress, image, permalinks

I have a wordpress installation with WPML and 2 Domains.

When I am in the Media library looking for a direct link of an image it shows:

```
www.youdomain.com/wp-content/uploads//xyz.de
```

same with the second domain:

```
www.youdomain.de/wp-content/uploads//xyz.png
```

How can I remove one `/` of the url in the source code ?

I already worked with better search replace but there are still images with `uploads//` in the source code.

Can someone suggest a solution for this problem ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use filter Attachment :

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', 'honor_for_attachments');
function honor_for_attachments($url) {
    $url = preg_replace('/([^:])(\/{2,})/', '$1/', $url);
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: This worked fine for the Backend. Thank you very much. 
Now I need to find a ways to remove the double slashed from source code of frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please Check the location where you are displaying image i think you have displayed extra slash there You can also refer the url

http://www.wpoye.com/how-to-remove-trailing-slash-from-wordpress-url/